# How do I use an arrayformula to autofill a column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-arrayformula, google

I have a script that automatically adds a new row to Tab 2 when a row is added on Tab 1. However I want my formulas on Tab 2 to autofill into the row that is added. Here is my formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(L2),ISNUMBER(M2)),(IF(COUNTIF(O2,"*"), "Y-REV", "Y")), "")
```

Trying to autofill into B2:B, but this didn't work with any of the ArrayFormulas I tried to make. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND()` is not compatible with ArrayFormulas, you need to find another calculation.
Furthermore we cannot use `COUNT()` because otherwise we would obtain a value that is always valid even if there was an asterisk in a single cell of column `O`, In its place we will use `REGEXMATCH()`

Try this:

```
=INDEX(IF(ISNUMBER(L2:L)*ISNUMBER(M2:M),IF(REGEXMATCH(" " &O2:O,"\*"), "Y-REV", "Y"), ""))
```

Comment: thank you so much, this almost worked! i was using countif "*" to see if the cell was  text because I didn't realize the istext function existed. For some reason your regexmatch does not work, but I replaced it with istextO2:O and that works perfectly!  thank you!! :)